# How to intensify color white in a video

Tags: color, color-grading

I'm doing a physics project and I measured the movement of some white spots on a field of wheat. Basically due to turbulence, there are spots with more intense wind and with wheat you see a white spot traveling. The issue is that in my video I have green grass with light white spots and I want to make those spots clearer, so they are easier to see in my video and make measurements based on it. How could I do it ?

Comment: What video software do you have available and what kind of computer are you using?

Comment: Davinci Resolve is what i would recommend to you. It has very powerful color correction and its free. I don't have access to a computer at the moment so i cant walk you through it right now but i would suggest you learn how to use color windows with davinci resolve and adjust the highlights of a clip